# cucumber java plugin not working properly in Intelij

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have been using my cucumber project on the Intelij for a very long time and it was working perfect. However, I upgraded the machine and so installed the latest version of Intelij.

I installed the cucumber-java plugin (and gherkins), however it doesn't work properly.

- I can't see option to run from feature file
- I can't go to step from feature file
- it doesn't understand Give/When/Then

Intelij Version: 2017.3.4
Cucumber-Java Version: 173.4301
Platform; Mac OS

Would someone please let me know what else I need to do to enable full support of cucumber java plugin?

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. Try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. In case the issue persists, [report the bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is it a Maven project (and if so, did you mark it as such?). I've found marking directories as source rout, test root etc has helped in this situation.

Comment: Also, which version of Cucumber are you using (if you recently also upgraded to Cucumber v2 that might be the reason as the cucumber plugin is not yet updated with cucumber v2)

Comment: Also Uninstalling/installing Plugin has helped me

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have the Substeps plugin in IntelliJ. If yes, uninstall it since Cucumber for java plugin does not work along with Substeps plugin

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem this might help you fix: Please check if you have ruby plugin also installed, which is needed for step definitions

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have Right Plugin, i had this issue , struggled for 2 days..

1) Have - Cucumber for Java

2) Remove (if you have it)- Cucumber (ion)for Java - Both have identical symbol.

Cross Check...

1) once you create .feature it will have right logo..

All the Best

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in [IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1. Build #IC-192.6262.58](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217391).

Answer (score -2):

I had faced a similar issue but on install "cucumber for Java" and "Gauge" plugin resolved this issue.